# Table without Repeating headers with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print my data in one table with headers and the data, but the headers are printed every line.

I'm using `Texttable` and already tried `PrettyTable` and tabulate to make the tables.

I'm using this code:

```
for T in T:

     k = (A*math.exp((-x)/T))/6.022E+23

     table = Texttable ()

     table.set_cols_align(["c", "c"])

     table.add_rows([["T", "k"],

                     [T, k]])

     print table.draw()
```

And my result is:

```
+-----+-------+
|  T  |   k   |
+=====+=======+
| 500 | 0.000 |
+-----+-------+
+-----+-------+
|  T  |   k   |
+=====+=======+
| 600 | 0.000 |
+-----+-------+
```

I expect the output table looks like this:

```
+-----+-------+
|  T  |   k   |
+=====+=======+
| 500 | 0.000 |
+=====+=======+
| 600 | 0.000 |
+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the header outside of the loop instead of adding it as a row in every iteration. And you should print the table outside of the loop. Tested, works.

```
table = Texttable ()
table.add_row(["T", "k"])
for T in T:
    k = (A*math.exp((-x)/T))/6.022E+23
    table.add_rows([T, k])

table.set_cols_align(["c", "c"])
print table.draw()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__len__'

Comment: texttable.ArraySizeError: array should contain 1 elements